# Java sorting object by a nested/related date

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, one-to-many

Im relatively new to Spring and Thymeleaf, but I have a list of Employee objects with a oneToMany relation for MeetingInfo. When I show my employee page it uses a list of employees with only the latest meeting. The data looks like this:

```
List after sorting: [Employee{employeeId=86, name='Color test', meetingInfo=[MeetingInfo{meetingId=38, message='Color test', meetingStartDateTime=2023-02-09 21:33:00.0, meetingEndDateTime=2023-02-09 22:33:00.0, meetingCreatedDate=2023-02-08 17:26:35.0, subject='color', location='Office', category='Battery', iconColor='Green', document='null'}]}, Employee{employeeId=91, name='john', meetingInfo=[MeetingInfo{meetingId=32, message='2nd meeting to discuss other stuff', meetingStartDateTime=2023-01-12 11:24:00.0, meetingEndDateTime=2023-01-12 11:30:00.0, meetingCreatedDate=2023-01-11 11:25:16.0, subject='2nd meeting', location='Some location', category='Discuss new project', iconColor='Green', document='null'}]}]
```

Edit: `meetingStartDateTime` is a Java `Date` object.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@Column(name = "meeting_start_date_time")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a")
private Date meetingStartDateTime;
```

How can I order this list so the most recent meetingStartDateTime is first and the older ones at the end?

I've tried some examples that override the compareTo method, but the examples I understand don't have nested dates. Whats the best approach here?

How I get my list:

```
@Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployeesWithLatestMeeting(List<Employee> employees) {
        List<Employee> newEmployeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
            List<MeetingInfo> meetingInfo = new ArrayList<>();
            Long id = employee.getEmployeeId();
            String name = employee.getName();
            MeetingInfo lastMeeting = getLatestMeetingById(id);
            meetingInfo.add(lastMeeting);
            newEmployee.setEmployeeId(id);
            newEmployee.setName(name);
            newEmployee.setMeetingInfo(meetingInfo);
            newEmployeeList.add(newEmployee);
        }
        return newEmployeeList;
    }
```

Controller (Using a basic pagination example)

```
@GetMapping("/employeePage/{pageNo}")
    public String findEmployeePaginated(@PathVariable(value = "pageNo") int pageNo,
                                       @RequestParam("sortField") String sortField,
                                       @RequestParam("sortDir") String sortDir,
                                       Model model) {
        int pageSize = 5;

        Page<Employee> page = employeeService.findPaginated(pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortDir);
        List<Employee> toSortEmployees = page.getContent();

        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNo);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());

        model.addAttribute("sortField", sortField);
        model.addAttribute("sortDir", sortDir);
        model.addAttribute("reverseSortDir", sortDir.equals("asc") ? "desc" : "asc");

        List<Employee> listEmployees = employeeService.getAllEmployeesWithLatestMeeting(toSortEmployees);
        model.addAttribute("listEmployees", listEmployees);
        return "meeting/home.html";
    }
```

And HTML

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><span>Status</span></th>
        <th><span><a th:href="@{'/ines/employeePage/' + ${currentPage} + '?sortField=name&sortDir=' + ${reverseSortDir}}">
            Employee</a></span>
        </th>
        <th><span>Last Meeting</span></th>
        <th><span>Message</span></th>
        <th><span>Add/View All/Delete</span></th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="employee : ${listEmployees}">
        <th:block th:each="latest : ${employee.meetingInfo}">
        <td align="center">
            <span th:switch="${latest.iconColor}">
                <i th:case="Yellow" class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation fa-2x" id="yellowWarning" title="3 months since last meeting"></i>
                <i th:case="Red" class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation fa-2x" id="redWarning" title="6 months since last meeting"></i>
                <i th:case="Green" class="fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-2x" id="greenWarning" title="Under 3 months since last meeting"></i>
            </span>
        </td>
            <td th:text="${employee.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${#calendars.format(latest.meetingStartDateTime,'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')}"></td>
            <td th:text="${#strings.abbreviate(latest.message,60)}"></td>
        </th:block>
```

Comment: Which is the type of `meetingStartDateTime`? You should use `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`  for it. I am asking because `2023-02-09 21:33:00.0` does not look like one of those, rather like a `java.sql.Timestamp`, a poorly designed, hacky class that no one should use anymore. Or maybe it’s simply a `String`, which is not good either. Can you fix that before we discuss how to sort by it?

Comment: Its a Java Date object. ```    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @Column(name = "meeting_start_date_time")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a")
    private Date meetingStartDateTime;```

Comment: *Its a Java Date object.* I am sorry, it is not exactly. `Date.toString()` cannot produce `2023-02-09 21:33:00.0` (or did `MeetingInfo.toString()` format that??) I see that your field has type `Date`. Most likely it holds a reference to a `java.sql.Timestamp` object (which is possible because `Timestamp` is ugly implemented as a subclass of `Date`.

Comment: In any case that should be (not tested, forgive typos): `listEmployees.sort(Comparator.comparing(emp -> emp.getMeetingInfo().isEmpty() ? null : emp.getMeetingInfo().get(0), Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(MeetingInfo::geMeetingStartDateTime).reversed()))):`.

Comment: Dude awesome, thank you so much. And sorry meetingStartDateTime is not an Object, MeetingInfo is the object. Works perfect, thanks again.

Comment: Do you mind explaining it? I only understand up until .get(0)

Comment: Do you know a bot about comparators? The `Comparator` interface is powerful for expressing the way we want the list sorted. I first call the two-arg `Comparator.comparing()`. The first argument is the *key extractor* that instructs Java how to get the sort key out of the `Employee` object. The second argument is a new comparator specifying how to sort the extracted keys. The sort key is the meeting info and may be null if the employee has never been in a meeting yet.

Comment: ... So as comparator I specify a null safe comparator from `Comparator.nullsLast()` specifying that employees with no meeting info should com last. The argument to this method is a third comparator specifying how to sort meetings, namely by meeting start time. The call to `reversed()` says the should come in descending order, so newest meetings first.

Comment: Awesome, thanks heaps again. I have done a little with comparators but I've never seen the nullsLast method. I was fine up until then.